# Web Deploy in Azure wont create publish profiles?

Tags: azure, webdeploy

When I do the steps to activate Web Deploy for a Windows Azure Web Role it won't create publish profiles. This used to work like a charm but now it won't work any more. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I have seen where the publish profile for staging and production do not get regenerated if you delete them.  Not sure how to actually do that - would love to know...  But, never seen the profiles NOT show up at least once.

Comment: I've got exactly this same issue. Can't see any obvious reason for it, nor an easy solution.

Comment: I noticed the question was asked over a year ago - have you tried this with the new tools? Does it work OK now?